# Robots.txt Allow sub folder but not the parent

Tags: robots.txt

Can anybody please explain the correct `robots.txt` command for the following scenario.

I would like to allow access to:

`/directory/subdirectory/..`

But I would also like to restrict access to `/directory/` not withstanding the above exception.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Be aware that there is no real official standard and that any web crawler may happily ignore your *robots.txt*

According to [a Google groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help-Indexing/browse_thread/thread/dfa31079d671315a), the following works at least with GoogleBot;

```
User-agent: Googlebot 
Disallow: /directory/ 
Allow: /directory/subdirectory/
```

Comment: I wanted to dynamically allow sub-directories but not that first level, changing the Allow statement to `Allow: /directory/*/` works.

Comment: According to the robots.txt Wikipedia entry, the 'Allow' directive should be placed before the 'Disallow' for maximum compatibility (though neither Google or Bing will mind)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using Google's robot tester.  Utilize Google Webmaster tools - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

You can edit and test URLs right in the tool, plus you get a wealth of other tools as well.

Comment: Good point! Not sure if that was available back in 2011 when I posted this, but it's a very useful addition to WMT.

Comment: QFDEV I had to use the Robot tester today because I am working really hard to get our companies site ranking higher on Google's Search Results. And the only thing I see under "HTML Improvements" on are duplicate titles and meta tags. This is because they are reading the same pages twice (query strings).  Also for some reason the robot is crawling directories that do not exist. I found your post, which helped and then noticed the tester in Google Web Master tools and saw that it would validate the changes. Thought it could help other developers by posting to your thread.

Answer (score 2):

If these are truly directories then the accepted answer is probably your best choice. But, if you're writing an application and the directories are dynamically generated paths (a.k.a. contexts, routes, etc), then you might want to use meta tags instead of defining it in the robots.txt. This gives you the advantage of not having to worry about how different browsers may interpret/prioritize the access to the subdirectory path.

You might try something like this in the code:

```
if is_parent_directory_path
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
end
```