# Robots.txt disallowing folder but allowing subfolders

Tags: seo, google-search, robots.txt

I'm trying to set it up where `www.url.com/folder` is disallowed, but `www.url.com/folder/1` is allowed. I have it set up as follows:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder
Allow: /folder/*
```

which works when testing with the Google robots.txt tester, but if I look at the logs, I can see Googlebot hitting all of the urls other than /folder.

Am I missing something? Should allow go first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Robots.txt Allow sub folder but not the parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609031/robots-txt-allow-sub-folder-but-not-the-parent)

Comment: "all of the urls other than /folder" -- Which URLs are these, and which do you want to disallow?

Comment: Any other URL on the site, i.e. /about. I removed the /folder restrictions from the file for now, see if that changes anything.

Answer (score -2):

I think this one should work:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /folder/$
Allow: /folder/*
```